# How to convert a LambdaExpression to typed Expression<Func<T, T>>

Tags: c#, .net, casting, lambda, linq-expressions

I'm dynamically building linq queries for nHibernate.

Due to dependencies, I wanted to cast/retrieve the typed expression at a later time, but I have been unsuccessfull so far.

This is not working (the cast is supposed to happen elsewhere):

```
var funcType = typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, typeof (bool));
var typedExpression =  (Func<T, bool>)Expression.Lambda(funcType, itemPredicate, parameter); //Fails
```

This is working:

```
var typedExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(itemPredicate, parameter);
```

Is it possible to get the 'encapsulated' typed expression from a LambdaExpression?

Comment: maybe you are looking for typedExpression.Compile()

Comment: I need to use the expression as an IQueryable with my ORM mapper so it can not be compiled.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var typedExpression =
    (Func<T, bool>)Expression.Lambda(funcType, itemPredicate, parameter); //Fails
```

This is not surprising, as you have to [`Compile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928.aspx) a `LambdaExpression` in order to get an actual delegate that can be invoked (which is what `Func<T, bool>` is).

So this would work, but I 'm not sure if it is what you need:

```
// This is no longer an expression and cannot be used with IQueryable
var myDelegate =
    (Func<T, bool>)
    Expression.Lambda(funcType, itemPredicate, parameter).Compile();
```

If you are not looking to compile the expression but instead to move an expression tree around, then the solution is to instead cast to an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`:

```
var typedExpression = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>) 
                      Expression.Lambda(funcType, itemPredicate, parameter);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Yes I'm looking to move the expression tree around.
The problem is the cast which you're refering to  `Expression<Func<T, bool>> typedExpression =
    Expression.Lambda(funcType, itemPredicate, parameter);`  This results in  
`Cannot convert souce type System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression to target type System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MyType, object>>`

Comment: @Larantz: Sorry, my mistake; I forgot that you need to cast explicitly. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you.  
I can not belive how blind I was not to notice that I was lacking the Expression<> part of the cast :).

Comment: Explicit cast `var typedExpression = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>) (...)` solved my similar issue.