# how to convert LambdaExpression.Body to Expression<Func<...>> without generic

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions

This is very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213005/how-to-convert-a-lambdaexpression-to-typed-expressionfunct-t) however, I don't have type information at build time. I have `Type` variable. How would I cast `LambdaExpression` to `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` where `T` is only known during run time?

Update:
Here is what i am doing

```
var funcType1 = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(nullablePropertyType, typeof(bool));
var funcType2 = typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(funcType1);
var expressionFunc = Expression.Convert((filterPredicate as LambdaExpression), funcType2);
```

The last line is giving me this error message

> "No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Func`2[MyType,System.Boolean]' and 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[MyType,System.Boolean]]'."

Stepping back, i want to do cast because while the lambdaexpression actually have `Expression<Func<MyType,bool>>`, I get error saying Linq to Entities can't process it...

Comment: You can't "cast" with an unknown type, since all casting does is change how the _compiler_ interacts with the object.  Can you share more about what you are trying to accomplish - maybe there's another way to solve it other than casting?

Comment: So if the `filterPredicate` already is of the type you need, but EF cannot understand what's inside it, then no casting whatsoever will help. Rather you have to use a predicate with no expressions in it's body that cannot translate to SQL.